# xaml style as static resource how to have error on compilation rather than execution if not exist

Tags: xaml, staticresource, xamlparseexception

Well, all is in the title.

In your App.xaml, you declare the style as follow

```
<Style x:Key="MyCustomLabelStyle" TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Red"/>
</Style>
```

In your xaml page, you declare a label with the name of the style but no luck you miss spell the x:Key, for exemple

```
<Label Style="{StaticResource MyCustomLabelStyl}"/>
```

instead of

```
<Label Style="{StaticResource MyCustomLabelStyle}"/>
```

if the style is not present or is present but with an other name, the app throw an exception at runtime.
That's perfectly normal.

My question is :
is there a way to have a compilation error when you miss spell a style key, like with compilated binding when you use x:DataType.

Thanks for your time and have a good day.